# Как вытащить CSRF из Заголовков

Tags: python, requests

помогите разобраться

```
import requests


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'X-CSRF-Token':     'sonIN6v5THcPkSMDLz5YXkQ_wC1vmC4PAwzHyxakJoaEx79ByMoIWmXTalViXC1vHAeEa1v_HUtBP_P5UuxP1Q==',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Origin': 'https://test.ru',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://test.ru/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
}

data = {
    '_csrf': 'sonIN6v5THcPkSMDLz5YXkQ_wC1vmC4PAwzHyxakJoaEx79ByMoIWmXTalViXC1vHAeEa1v_HUtBP_P5UuxP1Q==',
    'LoginForm[username]': 'sfgpsp@mail.ru',
    'LoginForm[password]': '564asfas',
    'LoginForm[rememberMe]': '1',
    'ajax': 'login-form',
}

response = requests.post('https://test.ru/login/validate/',   headers=headers, data=data)
```

Мне нужно написать чекер аккаунтов под такой сайт,но мне после каждой авторизации нужен будет новый csrf подкажите как вытащить его из заголовка, я умею вытаскивать из ответов с помощью BeautifulSoup, а вот с заголовков не могу понять как.

Comment: Ну примерно так. Создаем сессию. Делаем GET-запрос на 'test.ru/login/validate'. Вытаскиваем '_csrf'. Делаем POST-запрос с data.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = requests.Session()
res1 = s.get('https://oneclickmoney.ru',headers=headers)
csrf = dict(res1.cookies)['_csrf']
```

напиши мне в тг @poilka_polka